# White color objects not visible outside the artboard!

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, artboard

The white color objects are now not visible outside the artboard. It wasn't like this before, it occurred after changing the artboard background from document setup. Is there any way to change the artboard color without making the white objects turn invisible?

Comment: If I understand your question, You can't change the artboard background color, all what you can change from Document Setup is the grid color.

Comment: Did you put overprint preview on? That makes artboard white.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you changed your artboard background to white, you won't be able to see solid white objects unless you select them with the selection tool. This is just because there is nothing to differentiate the white object from white background, not because the actual white object was changed.

To see your white object on white background you can do one of the following:

1. Change your artboard to a darker color by going to
   **Preferences** -> **User Interface** -> **Brightness** -> **and select the color you want**.
2. You might also be in 'overprint preview', which changes your
   artboard to white. You can select and de-select this mode by going
   to **View -> Overprint Preview**. Make sure there is no check mark
   next to the Overprint selection. You can also use the keyboard
   shortcut <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> +
   <kbd>Y</kbd>
3. If you have an all white artboard and want to see the outlines of
   your objects, or if you're in overprint mode, you can also view
   everything in **Outlines** by selecting **View -> Outline**, or by
   typing <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>

Comment: Nice answer! Welcome to GD.SE.

Comment: Good answer.. another option.. turn on the transparency grid :)